# Terraform - retrieve specific attribute from module outputs when using a for_each in the call

Tags: azure, terraform

I wonder if it's possible to pick a specific attribute from module outputs, knowing that I'm using a loop when I call the module.
The sequence is:

1. call backup_policy module with a for_each on a map
2. policies are created and their id are provided in module output
3. call vm module and specify in the call the policy id with which the vm must be linked

Here are the code samples:

Call to backup_policy module:

```
locals {
  backup_policies = {
    "daily-critical" = {
    ...
    }
    "daily-qa" = {
    ...
    }
  }
}

module "backup_policy" {
  source = "path/to/my/module"

  for_each = local.backup_policies

  location            = local.location
  resource_group_name = module.rg.resource_group_name

  vm_backup_policy_name = "${each.key}-backup-policy"
}
```

backup_policy module code:

```
resource "azurerm_backup_policy_vm" "vm_backup_policy" {
  name                = var.vm_backup_policy_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  recovery_vault_name = var.recovery_vault_name
  ....
  }
```

backup_policy module output code:

```
output "vm_backup_policy_id" {
  value       = azurerm_backup_policy_vm.vm_backup_policy.id
}
```

Now that my policies are created, I want to link them to virtual machines using the policy id. But I want to specify which policy must be linked with which vm by using the policy name. Roughly it would look like that (please see the last line):

```
locals {
  location = "East US"

  vms = {
    "my-vm1" = {
      size          = "Standard_DS12_v2"
      backup_policy = "daily-critical"
    }
    "my-vm2" = {
      size          = "Standard_DS12_v2"
      backup_policy = "daily-qa"
    }
  }
}

module "vms" {
  source = "path/to/my/module"

  for_each            = local.vms
  vm_name             = each.key
  location            = local.location
  resource_group_name = module.rg.resource_group_name

  backup_policy_id = module.backup_policy.vm_backup_policy_id[each.value["backup_policy"]]
}
```

Is it possible or do I have to send to my backup_policy module a list of name and do the for_each on module's side so I can generate a map in the output?

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? Any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches that you can take to solving this type of problem (i.e. you have two separate, but related resources/modules that you want to create using for_each).

The first is essentially what you are asking about. For this you just need to fix one line in your code.

```
backup_policy_id = module.backup_policy.vm_backup_policy_id[each.value["backup_policy"]]
```

should be

```
backup_policy_id = module.backup_policy[each.value["backup_policy"]].vm_backup_policy_id
```

The other approach which I tend to favour, is to compose such dependent resources/modules into a single module and have them created together. For example:

```
# ./modules/my-combined-module/main.tf

variable "location" {}
variable "resource_group_name" {}
variable "vm_backup_policy_name" {}
variable "vm_name" {}


module "backup_policy" {
  source                = "../ba"
  location              = var.location
  resource_group_name   = var.resource_group_name
  vm_backup_policy_name = "${each.key}-backup-policy"
}

module "vms" {
  source = "../vm"

  vm_name             = var.vm_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  backup_policy_id    = module.backup_policy.vm_backup_policy_id
}
```

And then just run

```
module "my_combined_module" {
  source   = "./modules/my-combined-module"
  for_each = local.vms

  vm_name               = each.key
  vm_backup_policy_name = each.value["backup_policy"]
  location              = local.location
  resource_group_name   = local.resource_group_name
}
```

Comment: hello @Karl and thank you for fixing my line of code. I'll stay with this option because I want to keep it modular an reusable for other projects. Solution approved!